# BIND: enabling logging of denied queries

Tags: logging, bind

Im trying to get bind 9.11 (default on CentOS 8) to log queries, wich could not been answered or that lists clients that constantly querying the server, but are not allowed to.

Finally I want to use this logging to feed it to fail2ban and block those "idiots".

The server is a primary NS responsible to answer queries about domains its holds, but nothing more.

First I tried to log everything, like described in https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01526 even with full debug level, but never found a logline including the word "denied" or similar, except when somebody asked for a complete zone transfers (wich are surely only allowed from the secondary NS) like this:

27-Aug-2020 11:40:47.317 client @0x7fd284052510 94.102.208.167#51041 (somedomain.com): zone transfer 'somedomain.com/AXFR/IN' denied

When asking the server with a query for a name he is not responsible for, the client gets an:

```
dig @ns.mydomain.com www.disney.com
Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find www.disney.com: No answer
```

what is right, but bind only logs something like this:

27-Aug-2020 11:43:27.741 queries: info: client @0x7fd2840bf440 1.2.3.4#34369 ([www.disney.com](http://www.disney.com)): query: [www.disney.com](http://www.disney.com) IN A + (x.x.x.x)

which gives me no clue, what kind of answer was send to the client.

Current config is:

```
logging {
        channel "my_queries" {
                file "/var/log/named.queries" versions 600 size 20m;
                print-time yes;
                print-category yes;
                print-severity yes;
                severity dynamic;
        };
        channel "security_file" {
                file "/var/log/named.security";
                severity dynamic;
                print-time yes;
        };
        category "queries" { "my_queries"; };
        category client { "security_file"; };
        category security { "security_file"; };
        category lame-servers { null; };
};
```

So: how can I create logentries for clients that where not allowed to ask the server in the first place ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I see :

```
27-Aug-2020 13:33:17.170 security: info: client @0x7f88b57bdf90 192.168.10.165#18237 (www.google.com): view 192.168.10.0/24: query (cache) 'www.google.com/AAAA/IN' denied
27-Aug-2020 13:33:17.170 query-errors: info: client @0x7f88b57bdf90 192.168.10.165#18237 (www.google.com): view 192.168.10.0/24: query failed (REFUSED) for www.google.com/IN/AAAA at ../../../bin/named/query.c:7144
```

My configuration is (in `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`) :

```
logging {
  channel replace_syslog {
    file "/var/log/bind/named.log" versions 5 size 2m;
    severity info;
    print-time yes;
    print-category yes;
    print-severity yes;
    };
  category default { replace_syslog; default_debug; default_syslog ; };
  category lame-servers { null; };
  channel query.log {
    file "/var/log/bind/query.log" versions 2 size 2M;
    severity debug 3;
    print-time yes;
  };
  category queries { query.log; };
};
```

Comment: Do you see this REFUSED line in your /var/log/bind/query.log ? Or the named.log ? Or syslog ?

Comment: And. Did you enable debugging on startup of named ?

Comment: @phade : No debug enabled in Bind. The log is in /var/log/bind/named.log and in syslog too.  https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01526 says it is the channel "query-errors_log" who is responsible of these logs